# GCC/G++-11 on windows

Tags: windows, gcc, g++

Hey I'm trying to compile a program that requires GCC and g++ 11. I've tried msys2 but it only goes up to GCC 10.04
And some of my libraries are supposed to be built on a mingw like environment. So is there any other way of running that program on a windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest MinGW-w64 GCC build from https://winlibs.com/